# Force Magento to use only one URL in all listings

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

My problem is the following: Magento creates URL rewrites for new products and uses different URLs on different listings. If my product is in two categories `Foo` and `Bar`, Magento will use two URLs on top of the one I actually want.

- In category listing `Foo => /store/type/foo/product.html`
- In category listing `Bar => /store/type/bar/product.html`
- In normal linking `/store/product.html`

I want/need to get Magento to use only the URL `/store/product.html` throughout the entire store. I have not found any setting in the admin pages for that.

Using Magento `1.5.1.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, Magento ignored the setting for all the stores. After searching the code, I found that the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Url::getUrl()` checks this setting with `$product->getDoNotUseCategoryId()`. I called this method, and it returned `NULL` for all the products.

To solve this, I overloaded this method in my own product class:

```
public function getDoNotUseCategoryId(){
    return true;
}
```

This works.

It might be a problem with a non-existent attribute or something, but as long as this works I'll use it.

Answer (score 3):

Change "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" property in System -> Configuration -> Catalog to "No".

Comment: Try to rebuild URL index. It this will not help than I don't know what can be bad here...

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple way to do this for every where, copy Url.php from `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product` and past URl.php into `app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product`. After that need to update `getUrl` function.

Find this line: `$categoryId = $product->getCategoryId() && !$product->getDoNotUseCategoryId()
                ? $product->getCategoryId() : null;` and update with `$categoryId = $product->getCategoryId() && Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/product_use_categories')
                ? $product->getCategoryId() : null;`

Hope this will help someone.